# Print on thermal paper

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, crystal-reports

I need to print a receipt on thermal paper from Crystal Reports. I created a  print layout which works fine if printed from the preview. If I try to print from code, the printer just rolls out empty paper. The printer is installed properly (POS58). How can I properly print this from code?

```
ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
rptDoc.Load(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Reports\receipt.rpt");
rptDoc.SetParameterValue("pOrderID",OrderID);
rptDoc.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "POS58";
rptDoc.PrintToPrinter(1,false,0,0);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Guys,
Is any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment on your question, I am going to ask you here: Do you have any data on the report to show? I don't see any datasource assignment in your code, so maybe you need to provide some data to be printed.

Have you tried setting the paperSize in your code using the PrintOption in your report? I did this once; I was printing to a receipt printer but my paper was set to A4 so my actual report data were printed outside of the receipt paper. Try to send your document to a printer with A4 paper or better yet send it to oneNote so you don't waste paper and see how it prints.

Comment: Hi Sulieman,
Thank you for your reply, finally somebody try to help. As I mentioned I am using Crystal Reports. On the CR designer I put together the data tables and from the code I just give a parameter "OrderID". When I am in the CR designer and press the preview button, I see the print layout. When I press the Print button, the Printer is working fine, prints the receipt as I am expected. The screenshots above are the CR settings. Right click on the CR report in the designer. You can see the paper size is correct. Do I need to set from code as well? I don't find this paper size in .NET

Comment: Hi Suleiman, I printed the receipt to the Bullzip printer and I saw the receipt in the middle of the A4 size paper. I started to play the printer settings again, and a miracle happened. At the moment it is printing fine. You can believe me, I did try this many times. Unfortunately I don't know which settings helped. I think it was something in the printer driver settings My code is the same. Thank you for your suggestion. Sorry I cannot give you a point, my reputation is not enough.

Comment: one last thought on this check if your receipt printer is the default printer. If it might be that the paper settings are being taken from your default printer and not your receipt printer. If you do a lot of receipt printing check  [POS .Net](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42081). or try printing directly to your printer using .Net printing.